# Cargar gráficos de un Excel y luego guardarlo, con phpspreedsheet

Tags: php, phpexcel

Estoy usando PhpSpreedSheet para cargar un excel, actualizarlo y volver a guardarlo... El problema que me encuentro es que no lo guarda bien por los gráficos, y cuando abres el excel te dice lo típico de que ha habido un problema y "¿Desea que intentemos recuperar el máximo de contenido posible?" y quita los gráficos..

*Excel ha completado la validación y reparación en nivel de archivo. Puede que se hayan reparado o descartado algunas partes de este libro.
Parte quitada: Parte Propiedades del documento.  (Forma de dibujo)
Parte quitada: Forma de dibujo.
Parte quitada: Forma de dibujo.*

En el código tengo tanto en el reader el includecharts a true

```
    $reader = IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
    $reader->setIncludeCharts(true);
```

y en el writer lo mismo

```
    $writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($this->spreadsheet);
    $writer->setIncludeCharts(true);
```

He modificado los gráficos por menos complejos en cuestión de estética, pero nada...